# Python data abstraction on top of PeeWee

Tags: python, orm, dao, dto, peewee

It's more of a general question but I am trying to implement this using Python on top of Peewee as ORM. What is a decent OO way of abstracting the DB out of a python program?

In Peewee , classes are defined which inherit from peewee.Model and have Peewee fields as attributes.For example:

```
class Person(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

    name = peewee.TextField()
    height = peewee.DecimalField()
```

In an OO implementation we would like to have methods such as grow(size), die(),.. to be part of the objects. Is it best to build a class on top of these Peewee models to contain such functionality or should this be put in the model itself?

I can remember in a Java EE program that we used to have a DAO (Data access object) and DTO (Data transfer object). The peewee model object is a DAO or can it be both? Is there some sort of pattern that can be applied here?

Answer (score 2):

Peewee is an ActiveRecord ORM, so there's no distinction between the data access and the object representation. This means when you execute queries the data is returned to you as model instances. Given that this is the case, it's common to put methods on the model itself, since you're using it anyways.

Whether you want to build a service layer on top of your models is entirely up to you. If you have mutually-dependent models this may make sense.